# Export contents of the Openshift image to a file

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I've been searching for this for a while. I don't have access to the binary items used to build the image because an artifactory migration ruined the repo. There is one particularly precious binary I would love to extract from the image. I know `docker save` would save me, but I don't have access to docker, only to the `oc` client.

**EDIT:**

After looking around a little, thought that docker-registry API should be the way to go. Debugging `oc` client and logs of the docker-registry pods, found that both v1 and v2 API versions seem to be used.

Somehow cannot get any further than the version check.

Getting the auth token and registry url from oc:

```
TOKEN=`oc whoami -t`
URL="https://"`oc -n default get route docker-registry -o jsonpath="{.status.ingress[0].host}"
```

Then getting a correct response to:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "$URL/v2/"
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

but:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "$URL/v2/_catalog"
...
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Answer (score 2):

You can log in to the internal image registry if exposed and then pull the image back down to your local system and do what you want with it. Instructions for logging in can be found in:

- http://cookbook.openshift.org/image-registry-and-image-streams/how-do-i-push-an-image-to-the-internal-image-registry.html

That talks about doing a push, but you want to do a pull.

Comment: Thanks Graham, but doesn't it require using docker? I am on a client that does not have it.

Comment: Perhaps look at skopeo then. You are going to need some tool to be able to talk to the remote registry and work with the image. With skopeo at least, you don't need to install a local docker container daemon. https://github.com/projectatomic/skopeo

Comment: Looks like the right thing for the job, will try soon, thanks.